# Private Object "Attempted to access a missing member" exception

Tags: c#, .net, private-members, privateobject.invoke

I am trying to invoke a private method of an object using private method. This method takes three arguments. Both signature of method i am trying to invoke and the code invoking this method are shown below

Signature of private method:

```
Public Class Foo
{
  private void SaveCallback(SaveAggregationViewResponse response,
                                         Action rollbackActionIfSaveFails,
                                         Action postSaveActionOnSuccess)
  {}
}
```

Code I am using to invoke method:

```
var foo=new Foo()
Private pFoo=new PrivateObject(foo);
var response=new SaveAggregationViewResponse();
pFoo.Invoke("SaveCallback",new object[]{response,(Action)null,(Action)null}); //this line throws exception
```

Exception Message:
Method `'Foo.SaveCallback' not found.`

Is there something wrong with the way I am invoking private method or some other setup is wrong?

Thank You

Comment: Can you show the exception is thrown?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Added Exception Message, should i add full exception details?

Comment: Why you remove the method name from your Foo class? If Foo looks like this, it con't compiled at all.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Sorry about that, i deleted method name by mistake.

Comment: Do you run it in Debug mode without optimization?

Comment: Yes i do run it in Debug mode, not sure about optimization though

Comment: Can you post your actual code - the code posted isn't correct and won't compile

Comment: Try to call this and show result. `var mi = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("SaveCallback", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I think i was found an alternate way to invoke this callback using Moq Callback method. Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it with a ParamArray instead of an array of objects

```
pFoo.Invoke("SaveCallback",response,null,null);
```

Not sure whether to include the nulls, get rid of them if it doesn't work.